# TcpClient response stream with POP3, cant read more then one line

Tags: c#, stream, pop3, tcpclient

I am working on my own lib for pop3 since i didnt find what I needed in the ones that were suggested here. My problem is when opening a message it can only read a line up to a certain point (usually a link in the text) and it stops, looping but not crashing. code is:

```
Data = "RETR 1" + CRLF;
szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);
txtLog.Text += RdStrm.ReadLine() + CRLF;
for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
{

    txtLog.Text += RdStrm.ReadLine() + CRLF;
}


string szTemp;
szTemp = RdStrm.ReadLine();
// here it's supposed to start reading the actual message
while(szTemp != "-")
    {

        txtLog.Text += szTemp + CRLF;
        szTemp = RdStrm.ReadLine();

    }
```

Comment: You don't need to prefix your titles with "C#". That's what tags are for.

Comment: The problem is most likely not with TcpClient, but with the way how you implement the protocol. If data is not coming through the most likely reason for that is that they are simply not being sent to your client. In addition, TcpClient returns NetworkStream and NetworkStream does NOT have ReadLine method that you are showing in your code -yet one more thing that is relevant but is not reflected in your question. The best advice I can give: check your code carefully and debug you protocol implementation.

Comment: @zespri 1, the full code includes: RdStrm = new StreamReader(Server.GetStream());                                                        i am getting response from all the commands, except from that while loop. if i do a for loop i am getting everything before the hyperlink in the email. So no the implementation is all good, just reading from the stream seems to be a problem

Comment: ReadLine reads until the end of the line (as the name implies) are you sure that the rest of whatever you are reading has a new line in it? This is likely to be your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Match reg1 = Regex.Match(ifOk, "OK(.*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (reg1.Success)
{
    txtLog.Text += "Ready To Start!\r\n";

    Data = "USER XXXX" + CRLF;
    szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
    NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);
    txtLog.Text += RdStrm.ReadLine() + CRLF;

    Data = "PASS XXXX" + CRLF;
    szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
    NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);
    txtLog.Text += RdStrm.ReadLine() + CRLF;

    Data = "STAT" + CRLF;
    szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
    NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);
    txtLog.Text += RdStrm.ReadLine() + CRLF + CRLF + CRLF + CRLF + CRLF;

    Data = "RETR 1" + CRLF;
    szData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data.ToCharArray());
    NetStrm.Write(szData, 0, szData.Length);
    txtLog.Text += RdStrm.ReadLine() + CRLF;

    string szTemp;

    szTemp = RdStrm.ReadLine();

    // POP3 uses . as the end of a message
    while(szTemp != ".")
    {                   
        txtLog.Text += szTemp + CRLF;
        szTemp = RdStrm.ReadLine();                                               
    }              
}
```

that settles it, looks like the internet is in a need for a good, open source, easy to modify lib, so that's what i'll do next. Thanks everyone. Works perfectly now

Answer (score 0):

If the service at the other end returns lines that end with CRLF, then the lines you get from Readline will have a CR at the end. 
So the returned string will always be != "-".